# Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'child.props.clone')

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

[While using react-native-router-flux am getting this error. I this is due to improper key set to scene 
thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfjkp.png)

Comment: add code please, or share git link on your project.

Comment: can you show the code ? :)